# AWS ALB and TLS termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, tls1.2, aws-application-load-balancer

My flow goes like this:

Client -> ALB -> k8s pod

What I'm trying to achieve is to have 2 TLS sessions: one between the Client and ALB and second between ALB and k8s pod. My ALB is an external one/internet-facing and I managed to correctly attach AWS ACM cert to it and successfully terminated the TLS session there. However now, I would like the second TLS session to be established between ALB and k8s pod. The problem is that my pod uses self-signed TLS keys. I think I somehow must notify the ALB that there is this self-signed CA cert that the ALB should "trust" so it can establish a secure TLS connection with the pod. Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Just make sure that the alb is forwarding the requests to the correct port where the application is listening on secure port. You can configure this in your target group.

Comment: @RahulSharma why is that so? How will ALB discover the CA of the self-signed TLS that I installed on my pod? Do you have any docs?

Comment: "How will ALB discover the CA of the self-signed TLS that I installed on my pod?" AWS ALBs do not validate the certificates of their targets. They don't care that the certificate is self-signed.

Comment: @MarkB how is that achieved? The certs are installed on the pod and even though the TLS handshake is not established between those 2 parties? I tried to find some documentation about that but I didn't find anything meaningful.

Comment: How is **what** achieved? All I did was leave a comment on what the default behavior of ALB is. It is also a behavior that you can't change. So what are you asking me how to achieve?

Comment: @MarkB sorry for misunderstanding. So the ALB only uses the TLS session to encrypt/decrypt the traffic between ALB and pod but it does not validate the TLS certs. Am I correct?

Comment: That is correct